# Add or override aes in the existing mapping object

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

Here's the minimal case:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=1, col=1:5)
mapping <- aes(x=x, y=y)
ggplot(df, mapping) + geom_point(size=10)
```

Now I want to add (or overwrite) another aesthetic (colour) to the existing `mapping` object. The desired plot is

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=col)) + geom_point(size=10)
```

I'm sure there exists a convenience function for this, but it is not listed in the documentation, and browsing the source didn't help either. I once seem to have stumbled upon something like `AddOrOverrideAes`, but no idea where exactly.

Here's what my current solution is:

```
add_aes <- function (mapping, ...) {
   new_aes <- structure(append(mapping, as.list(match.call()[-(1:2)])), class = "uneval")
   rename_aes(new_aes)
}

environment(add_aes) <- asNamespace("ggplot2")
ggplot(df, add_aes(mapping, colour=col)) + geom_point(size=10)
```

It works ok for addition, but not for overwriting (no check if this aes already exists, etc). Am I reinventing the wheel?

The motivation for this is GGally's `ggpairs` customization, see [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716567/use-ggpairs-to-create-this-plot)

**Edit:**

The workflow is as follows: get the existing `mapping` as a parameter, modify it in place and pass further to another function. I am not able to modify the "final" ggplot call.

Comment: Why not just `ggplot(df, mapping) + geom_point(size=10) + aes(colour=col)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the note, I didn't know that was possible! However, I need to pass the modified mapping further, to another function, so I cannot directly modify the final ggplot call.

Comment: aes is list so `ggplot(df, modifyList(mapping, aes(colour=col))) + geom_point(size=10)` works.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it seems to be what I'm looking for. Will you post this as an answer or should I do this myself?

Comment: @tonytonov It's been a day, so feel free to post the answer yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on @koshke's comment, here's a working example that does the job:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=1, new_y=5:1, col=1:5, new_col=factor(1:5))
mapping <- aes(x=x, y=y, col=col)
ggplot(df, mapping) + geom_point(size=10)

add_modify_aes <- function(mapping, ...) {
  ggplot2:::rename_aes(modifyList(mapping, ...))  
}

ggplot(df, add_modify_aes(mapping, aes(color=new_col, y=new_y))) + geom_point(size=10)
```

There's a slight modification that deals with aes collisions (i.e., `col`, `color`, `colour`).

Initial plot:[image]
Modified plot:[image]