# ggpairs() correlation values without gridlines

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I have this code that generates the plot below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)

data(iris)
ggpairs(data = iris[, 1:4], axisLabels = "none", switch = "both")
```

[image]
I'd like to do three things with this plot: 1) remove the gridlines in the correlation windows; 2) increase font size of the x-y axes labels; and 3) make these label-backgrounds white (instead of gray). The first question was addressed about 4 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716567/use-ggpairs-to-create-this-plot) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810675/ggallyggpairs-plot-without-gridlines-when-plotting-correlation-coefficient), and it seems one would need to either rebuild GGally package, or use a custom code from [GitHub](https://github.com/tonytonov/ggally/blob/master/R/gg-plots.r). Both options are pretty heavy for a newbie like me, and I am wondering if someone has figured out an easier method by now. I have not found my 2nd and 3rd questions addressed anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: try the `cor_fun` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889222/change-colors-in-ggpairs-now-that-params-is-deprecated/37890371#37890371 , although there may be easier ways now!

Comment: Make label backgrounds white and increase font size: `+ theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill="white", colour="black"),
        strip.text = element_text(size=15))`.

Comment: @eipi10 That's cool - thanks! I am also wondering if I over-complicated this by switching facet_labels from top+right to bottom+left (usng`switch = "both")`. Wish there is a simpler way, like turning off facet_labels and turning on axes-labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first request can be handled by:

```
+theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank())
```

The size of the axis labels (which are really in "strips" can be handled with this additional arguemnt to `theme`:

```
    ... , strip.text = element_text(size = 5))
```

Comment: The Society for the Preservation of the English Adverb would like to request that in the future you use "works perfectly".

Comment: Someone commented [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76214/something-worked-perfectly-vs-something-worked-perfect) that Perfect has been used as adverb since the 15th century :)

Comment: Non-standard is what it was called. Are you claiming that because you are in the hadleyverse that anything non-standard is acceptable?