# Modifying ggpairs plot to look like plotmatrix in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggally

```
require(GGally)
data(iris)

ggpairs(dd2, columns = 1:4,
        upper = list(continuous = "points"),
        lower = list(continuous = "cor",params = c(corSize = 10)), 
        diag = list(continuous = "bar"),
        axisLabels = 'show')
```

[image]

Is there a way to (1) make the background of the panels white i.e. similar to theme_bw() in ggplot2 and remove the grid lines ; (2) can I move the labels (i.e. mpg, cyl etc) to the top and right hand side of the figure, similar to how plotmatrix from ggplot2 looks like; (3) can I remove the Corr in the lower panels and only have the number shown.

I have found a few posts on here that do some of these but they all refer to changing the source?

Comment: You might have seen [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716567/use-ggpairs-to-create-this-plot) of my answers. I am almost sure that at least (2) and (3) are not customizable through parameters; so yes, modifying the source seems like the only way. This does not mean the code is "that bad", it is open and clear, so you don't have to be a super hacker to get things done.