# Remove unused facet combinations in 2-way facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two factors and two continuous variables, and I use this to create a two-way facet plot using ggplot2. However, not all of my factor combinations have data, so I end up with dummy facets. Here's some dummy code to produce an equivalent output:

```
library(ggplot2)
dummy<-data.frame(x=rnorm(60),y=rnorm(60),
                  col=rep(c("A","B","C","B","C","C"),each=10),
                  row=rep(c("a","a","a","b","b","c"),each=10))
ggplot(data=dummy,aes(x=x,y=y))+
       geom_point()+
       facet_grid(row~col)
```

This produces [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqbRz.png)

Is there any way to remove the facets that don't plot any data? And, ideally, move the x and y axis labels up or right to the remaining plots? As shown in [this GIMPed version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w9y0.png)

I've searched here and elsewhere and unless my search terms just aren't good enough, I can't find the same problem anywhere. Similar issues are often with unused factor levels, but here no factor level is unused, just factor level *combinations*. So `facet_grid(drop=TRUE)` or `ggplot(data=droplevel(dummy))` doesn't help here. Combining the factors into a single factor and dropping unused levels of the new factor can only produce a 1-dimensional facet grid, which isn't what I want.

Note: my actual data has a third factor level which I represent by different point colours. Thus a single-plot solution allowing me to retain a legend would be ideal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not too difficult to rearrange the graphical objects (`grobs`) manually to achieve what you're after.

1. Load the necessary libraries.

   ```
   library(grid);
   library(gtable);
   ```
2. Turn your `ggplot2` plot into a `grob`.

   ```
   gg <- ggplot(data = dummy, aes(x = x,y = y)) +
           geom_point() +
           facet_grid(row ~ col);
   grob <- ggplotGrob(gg);
   ```

   Working out which facets to remove, and which axes to move where depends on the grid-structure of your `grob`. `gtable_show_layout(grob)` gives a visual representation of your grid structure, where numbers like `(7, 4)` denote a panel in row `7` and column `4`.
3. Remove the empty facets.

   ```
   # Remove facets
   idx <- which(grob$layout$name %in% c("panel-2-1", "panel-3-1", "panel-3-2"));
   for (i in idx) grob$grobs[[i]] <- nullGrob();
   ```
4. Move the x axes up.

   ```
   # Move x axes up
   # axis-b-1 needs to move up 4 rows
   # axis-b-2 needs to move up 2 rows
   idx <- which(grob$layout$name %in% c("axis-b-1", "axis-b-2"));
   grob$layout[idx, c("t", "b")] <- grob$layout[idx, c("t", "b")] - c(4, 2);
   ```
5. Move the y axes to the right.

   ```
   # Move y axes right
   # axis-l-2 needs to move 2 columns to the right
   # axis-l-3 needs ot move 4 columns to the right
   idx <- which(grob$layout$name %in% c("axis-l-2", "axis-l-3"));
   grob$layout[idx, c("l", "r")] <- grob$layout[idx, c("l", "r")] + c(2, 4);
   ```
6. Plot.

   ```
   # Plot
   grid.newpage();
   grid.draw(grob);
   ```

[image]

Extending this to more facets is straightforward.

Comment: What is the pattern behind the panel naming `pane-2-1`, `panel-3-1`, etc ? One would expect it to be row-column. However, I had to modify a plot where the arrangement and naming of the panels was: 
row1:`"panel-1-1" | "panel-1-3"`  
row2:`"panel-2-1" | "panel-2-3"`  
row3:`"panel-1-2" | "panel-1-4"`  
row4:`"panel-2-2" | "panel-2-4"`  
Is there a general pattern or does one need to find out by trial and error?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious: Is there no option of automating the search for which panels to remove based on certain criteria?

Comment: @M.Teich That's a good question. Since the exact grid/matrix layout depends on what plot elements are shown and where, I haven't found a way to automate this other than taking a look at the output of `gtable_show_layout` and working out what's what. To see what I mean, consider moving the right facet strips to the left and observe how panel names have changed.

Answer (score 3):

Maurits Evers solution worked great, but is quite cumbersome to modify.
An alternative solution is to use [facet_manual from {ggh4x}](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html#manual-facets-1).

This is not equivalent though as it uses facet_wrap, but allows appropriate placement of the facets.

```r
# devtools::install_github("teunbrand/ggh4x")
library(ggplot2)

dummy<-data.frame(x=rnorm(60),y=rnorm(60),
                  col=rep(c("A","B","C","B","C","C"),each=10),
                  row=rep(c("a","a","a","b","b","c"),each=10))

design <- "
  ABC
  #DE
  ##F
"

ggplot(data=dummy,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  ggh4x::facet_manual(vars(row,col), design = design, labeller = label_both)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, of course, would be to create a plot for each factor combination separately and then combine them using `grid.arrange()` from `gridExtra`. This would probably lose my legend and would be an all around pain, would love to hear if anyone has any better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This particular case looks like a job for ggpairs ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716567/use-ggpairs-to-create-this-plot) to a SO example).  I haven't used it myself, but for paired plots this seems like the best tool for the job.

In a more general case, where you're not looking for pairs, you could try creating a column with a composite (pasted) factor and facet_grid or facet_wrap by that variable ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716567/use-ggpairs-to-create-this-plot))