# How do you add jitter to a scatterplot matrix in ggpairs?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I want to add jitter to a scatterplot matrix. The question was addressed on the following page (and nowhere else) on stackoverflow:

[How to produce a meaningful draftsman/correlation plot for discrete values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691302/how-to-produce-a-meaningful-draftsman-correlation-plot-for-discrete-values/21691950#21691950?newreg=76fe4e247ba7470ab3386a29be03b477)

But both solutions to the jitter problem which were suggested there involve deprecated code (plotmatrix and params):

```
library(ggplot2)
plotmatrix(y) + geom_jitter(alpha = .2)

library(GGally)
ggpairs(y, lower = list(params = c(alpha = .2, position = "jitter")))
```

I would have simply commented asking for an update there so as to not create a new question, but that appears to require reputation points, and I'm new to the site. My apologies if I've done something wrong in posting the question.

EDIT:

Here's what the data looks like:

```
> str(EHRound4.subset)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   301 obs. of  22 variables:
$ Subject#         : int  1 2 3 4 6 7 8 13 14 16 ...
$ Condition        : Factor w/ 2 levels "CDR","Mturk": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 ...
$ Launch4          : int  5 8 8 5 8 5 3 8 5 6 ...
$ NewSong4         : int  6 8 8 6 8 6 8 8 8 7 ...
$ StudCom5         : int  6 5 8 3 1 3 4 8 7 7 ...
$ Textbook5        : int  8 1 8 3 1 7 8 8 8 8 ...
```

And here's several attempts at getting jitter.

```
> ggpairs(EHRound4.subset, columns = 3:6, 
ggplot2::aes(colour=Condition), lower = list(geom_jitter(alpha = .2)))

> ggpairs(EHRound4.subset, columns = 3:6, 
ggplot2::aes(colour=Condition, alpha=.2), lower = list(geom_jitter()))

> ggpairs(EHRound4.subset, columns = 3:6, 
ggplot2::aes(colour=Condition, alpha=.2, position="jitter"))
```

Comment: To improve the question, please consider adding plotting code with example data, showing your plot without the jittering. Ideally, we should be able to easily run your code.

Comment: use `wrap` ... `lower = list(continuous=wrap("points", position="jitter"))`

Comment: That worked, thank you very much!

Comment: you're welcome - please feel free to write up . (ps to get more control of the jitter you can use `lower = list(continuous=wrap("points", 
                             position=position_jitter(height=3, width=3)))`

Comment: I figured out the position_jitter() call, but thank you! What do you mean "write up"?

Comment: @emory989 ; i meant to write it in the answer section below

Answer (score 6):

@user20650 answered the question in comments below the question. For completeness, here it is in the form of an answer:

Use `wrap`, such as:

```
library(GGally)
ggpairs(y, lower = list(continuous=wrap("points", position=position_jitter(height=3, width=3))))
```

By using `position = position_jitter()` instead of just `position = "jitter"` (which also works) the additional jitter parameters can also be controlled.